# Rails: What is `sanitize` in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

What does `sanitize` mean in Rails?

I'm reading through the documentation for `CanCanCan`. It says:

> When using strong_parameters or Rails 4+, you have to sanitize inputs
>   before saving the record, in actions such as :create and :update.

Then per documentation, it requires adding the below:

```
load_and_authorize_resource param_method: :my_sanitizer

def my_sanitizer
  params.require(:article).permit(:name)
end
```

Source: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

I've also seen `sanitize` in the area of SQL queries.

What does `sanitize` mean actually. Does it just mean to allow something?

Comment: Sanitize means cleaning anything to make it hygiene here for your application. So that your application doesn't save unwanted data which can cause serious issues like hacking or broken app. Checkout the doc here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html and here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

Comment: Also, try to avoid subjective questions on SO. Ideally you should be asking a problem related to your code given your points on SO you should have known this already. Cheers!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SanitizeHelper` module provides a set of methods for scrubbing text of undesired HTML elements. These helper methods extend Action View making them callable within your template files.

`data = data.html_safe` will just mark string `data as 'html_safe'` and treat it as such afterwards (Marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no additional escaping performed. It is your responsibility to ensure that the string contains no malicious content. This method is equivalent to the raw helper in views. It is recommended that you use sanitize instead of this method. It should never be called on user input.).

Have a look at official api doc
[action view sanitize helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)